# Odoo - Populate field with data

Tags: odoo

I added a product to a ticket:

```
class TicketExt(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'helpdesk.support'
    product = fields.Many2many('product.template',string='Product')
```

Now I want to display the ticket that is related to the product:

```
class ProductExt(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'
    p_tickets = fields.Many2many('helpdesk.support','product', string='Tickets' )
```

---

```
<record id="product_template_common_form_ticket_ext" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">product.template.common.form.ticket.ext</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//page[@name='notes']" position="after">
            <page string='Tickets' >
                <field name="p_tickets"  />
            </page>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

---

I can add new tickets to a product, but the tickets that have been added previously, do not show up.

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add common relation field and reference fields in your definition.

```
product = fields.Many2many('product.template', 'product_ticket_rel', 'ticket_id', 'product_id')
```

and

```
p_ticket = fields.Many2many('helpdesk.ticket','product_ticket_rel','product_id','ticket_id')
```

See reference on https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/orm.html

And sometimes it is hard to select which one you should use `product.product` or `product.template`

Comment: thanks, but now I get `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "_unknown" does not exist
LINE 1: ...uct_ticket_rel.ticket_id FROM product_ticket_rel, "_unknown"`

Comment: Ah, it's `helpdesk.support` and not `helpdesk.ticket`. Now it works. Many thanks

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was hasty writing my example. Happy to hear that this helped.